# Angular Routing on root path with parameter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to configure the paths on my angular routes to have an ID paramter on the empty root path. For example `localhost:4200/123` where as my current working code works like `localhost:4200/view/123`

Here is my current working routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
  {path: 'view/:id', component: ViewComponent},
];
```

Ideally I want to scrap the `/view/` part of the path.

I've tried

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '/:id', component: ViewComponent},
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
];
```

with combinations of dropping the forward slash.

I've also tried

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '/:id', redirectTo: 'view', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
  {path: 'view', component: ViewComponent},
];
```

With combinations of dropping the forward slash and adding `/:id` to `{path: 'view', component: ViewComponent},`

When the I try the previously non-working routes, the page comes out blank and no errors in the console.

Using Angular 5.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: ':id', component: HomeComponent },
    ......
];
```

Comment: Actually removing the redirects works perfectly. Thank you, simple really!